# WPF Hidden ScrollViewer's Bars

Tags: wpf

I need a ScrollViewer for WPF application which like on some web pages (like Facebook), scroll bars are hidden even if content is long, but when mouse is over bars become visible. Anyone have idea how to do that?

Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVVM focused answer:

- I'm sure there is a property which allows you to hide or show the scroll bars.
- Bind this property to your ViewModel.
- Create a MouseOver event which fires when the mouse moves into a certain part of the screen. To do this, you could overlay an invisible grid over the screen, with the right hand 10% as the target area.
- Now when the mouse enters the region, show the scrollbar, and when it exits the region, hide the scrollbar.
- Ensure that you set the MinWidth on the invisible region, so that if the window gets narrow, the scrollbar trigger area is still wide enough to be usable.